# Is it possible to create an iOS app to control an Archos Internet Tablet?

Tags: android, objective-c, ios, wifi, archos

I got a request from a client to develop an iPhone app similar to Archos Remote Control (source: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.archos.remote). Before I start studying Objective-C, I'd like to know if this is possible and get a rough, general guideline of the interfaces I'd be working with.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a client and server app, Client app would be for the Archos, and the Server app would obviously go in the iOS device.